# SugarCRM Partial Uninstallation of package

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

Need help in partially uninstall each sugarcrm package using manifest.php

I have 2 products (let's say  X and Y ) ,each consists of 5 modules.

Out of 5 in X ,2 modules (let's say A and B ) are core which will required for Y.

C,D,E are related to X only.

My product will be uninstallable which will uninstall all 5 Modules, which I don't want as A and B can be Y as well.

I want to Uninstallation process don't uninstall A and B, as an instance can have my other products (Y) which need A and B.

Any clue to stop A and B if a user is going to uninstall X or Y.

Any Help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is this about already installed packages? Because otherwise you could just create a separate Package "Z" for A and B, that is both required by new X (C, D, E) and Y.
I guess even if already installed you could create those Z (A,B) and X (new version only containing C, D, E and requiring Z) packages and install them over the existing ones. Then uninstall the new X.

Comment: I am building products in which A and B will be common in all products. that's kind of core package. I don't want customers install a seperetae package just for getting A and B.